# How to solve 2D eigenvalue problem with robin boundary conditions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I need to solve an eigenvalue problem in 2D as seen in the picture.

[image]

I've tried the function `NDEigensystem` but reading its documentation it seems it has issues with non-homogeneous boundary conditions. As solution I need the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions.

I would be very thankful if anybody could suggest how to solve such eigenvalue problem.

Comment: I do not think NDEigensystem supports Robin BC (ie. both Dirichlet and Neumann on same boundary).

Comment: “it seems it has issues with non-homogeneous boundary conditions” Yeah, but yours is homogeneous!

Comment: @Nasser No, Robin b.c. can be defined with `NeumannValue`.

Comment: @xzczd good to know. I but I could not make it work myself.

Comment: @kpaz Could you show your attempt with `NDEigensystem`?

Answer (score 2):

Let me extend my comments to an answer.

> …it seems it has issues with non-homogeneous boundary conditions

Yes, but your b.c.s are homogeneous. `NeumannValue` can handle it, and we can use my [`allowfemdbc`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268449/1871) to automatically convert the b.c.s involving derivative to `NeumannValue`:

```
With[{u = u[x, y]}, lhs = Laplacian[u, {x, y}];
  bc = {u == 0 /. {{x -> -1}, {y -> -1}},
    {2 D[u, x] + u == 0 /. x -> 1,
     D[u, y] + u == 0 /. y -> 1}}];

tst = allowfemdbc[
   NDEigensystem[{lhs, bc} // Flatten, u, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 4, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
        "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]]
(* {{0.916814, -4.13089, -4.56846, -9.61616}, …} *)

Plot3D[tst[[2, 1]][x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Let's check if the Robin b.c.s are satisfied:

```
index = 2;
mid = Subtract @@@ bc[[2, 1]] /. u -> tst[[2, index]]; 
mid2 = Subtract @@@ bc[[2, 2]] /. u -> tst[[2, index]];
Plot[mid2, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All] ~Show~Plot[mid, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Not bad, and will be better if `MaxCellMeasure` is smaller. The following is obtained with `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001`:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. Why `NDEigensystem[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Lambda] u[x, y] ==
NeumannValue[- 1/2 u[x, y], x == 1] +NeumannValue[-  u[x, y], y == 1] , u[-1, y] ==$MachineEpsilon,u[x, -1 ] == $MachineEpsilon}, u,Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]],2]` doesn't work ?

Comment: `$MachineEpsilon` makes the b.c. inhomogeneous. As mentioned above, it's not allowed. @ulrich

Comment: Ok but also `NDEigensystem[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Lambda] u[x, y] == NeumannValue[- 1/2 u[x, y], x == 1] +NeumannValue[-  u[x, y], y == 1] , u[-1, y] ==0,u[x, -1 ] == 0}, u,Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]],2]` doesn't evaluate!

Comment: In your answer part `\[Lambda] u[x, y]` is missing I think

Comment: @ul First argument of `NDEigensystem` is not an equation, please check the document carefully.

Comment: That's it , thanks. First eigenfunction is quite similar to my answer ;-)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Oops, I made a mistake when coding `allowfemdbc`. Corrected. Now it's the same as yours :) .

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `NDEigensystem` doesn't evaluate. Perhaps `NDSolveValue` helps to describe the system with Robin boundaries and gives an idea about the shape of the eigenfunction:

```
\[Lambda] = 1;
U = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - \[Lambda] u[x, y] ==
NeumannValue[- 1/2 u[x, y], x == 1] +NeumannValue[-  u[x, y], y == 1] , u[-1, y] ==$MachineEpsilon,u[x, -1 ] == $MachineEpsilon}, u,Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]]

Plot3D[U[x, y], Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1,-1}, {1, 1}]]]
```

[image]

It looks like the problem has only trivial solution `u==0` (*Separation of variables* might show this result analytically)!

**addendum**
`NDEigensystem` works after all (thanks @xzczd's comments!)

```
es = NDEigensystem[{Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] - 
    NeumannValue[-1/2 u[x, y], x == 1] - 
    NeumannValue[-u[x, y], y == 1], u[-1, y] == 0, u[x, -1] == 0}, u, 
  Element[{x, y}, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]], 3]

Map[Plot3D[#[x, y], Element[{x, y},Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]]] &,es[[2]]]
```

[image]

Comment: `NDSolve` cannot be used to deal with eigenvalue problem (at least cannot be used in this manner), and `NDEigensystem` evaluates. See my answer.

Comment: @xzczd My focus was to show how to formulate the pde-problem.