# Convert boundary condition involving derivative to NeumannValue programmatically

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, code-generation

As discussed in e.g.

[what causes the error "The dependent variable in the boundary condition needs to be linear" when using NDSolve?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/224812/1871)

When `FiniteElement` method is chosen for spatial discretization in `NDSolve`, boundary condition (b.c.) involving `Derivative` (include but not limited to Neumann b.c. and Robin b.c. ) cannot be directly used. We have to convert such b.c. to `NeumannValue`. Can the process be automated, at least for regular domain?

Answer (score 3):

The following my (incomplete) attempt.

```
ClearAll[allowfemdbc];
forcetoeq[sys_] := 
  Replace[Flatten@{sys}, 
   expr : Except[_Equal | _DirichletCondition | _PeriodicBoundaryCondition] :> -expr ==
      0, {1}];

SetAttributes[allowfemdbc, HoldAll];
allowfemdbc[(head : NDSolve | NDSolveValue | NDEigenvalues | NDEigensystem)[sys_, 
   depend_, domain : Longest[{_, _, _} ..], n___Integer, rest : OptionsPattern[]], 
  wrapper_ : Identity] := 
 Module[{coordlst, boundLlst, boundRlst, dependvar, bc, bcfem, eq, dbc, bcrest, state,
    coefgrad, dim, asso, pde, neumann, dvar, bcpos, bcnew, gpu, 
   gpuvalue}, {coordlst, boundLlst, boundRlst} = {domain}\[Transpose];
  {dependvar} = Flatten@{depend} /. h_ @@ coordlst :> h;
  {bc, bcfem, eq} = 
   Internal`ProcessEquations`SeparateEquations[sys // forcetoeq, coordlst, 
     dependvar][[2 ;; 4]];
  dbc = Cases[bc, a_ /; ! FreeQ[a, Derivative]];
  bcrest = Complement[bc, dbc];
  state = Quiet[
    NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{eq, bcrest, bcfem}, depend, domain, rest][[1]], 
    NDSolve`ProcessEquations::femibcnd];
  coefgrad = 
   state["FiniteElementData"]["PDECoefficientData"]["DiffusionCoefficients"][[1]] . 
    Grad[-dependvar @@ coordlst, coordlst];
  dim = Length@coordlst;
  asso = Association@
    Flatten@{Thread[Thread[coordlst == boundLlst] -> -IdentityMatrix[dim]], 
      Thread[Thread[coordlst == boundRlst] -> IdentityMatrix[dim]]};
  pde = NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE[state][[1]];
  neumann = 
   Total@Table[{dvar, bcpos} = 
      Cases[traditionalbc, 
        term : Derivative[__][dependvar][a__] :> {term, 
          And @@ Thread[coordlst == {a}]}, Infinity, 1][[1]];
     bcnew = gpu == coefgrad . asso[bcpos] /. Rule @@ bcpos;
     gpuvalue = SolveValues[{bcnew, traditionalbc}, gpu, {dvar}][[1]];
     NeumannValue[gpuvalue /. h_ @@ dvar :> dependvar @@ coordlst, 
      bcpos], {traditionalbc, dbc}];
  wrapper[head][
   Sow@Flatten@{If[MatchQ[head, NDEigenvalues | NDEigensystem], -(pde + neumann), 
       pde == neumann], bcrest, bcfem}, depend, domain, n, rest]]
```

To understand the code, you may want to read the following posts:

[What is the best way to parse differential equations and boundary conditions to a custom function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221840/1871)

[Reveal the formal PDE of FiniteElement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/225711/1871)

### Known issues

1. Currently it cannot deal with PDE system.
2. Time dependent PDE is not supported for now, but when the PDE is time dependent in a regular domain, we can use the old good `TensorProductGrid`, don't we?
3. `∈` syntax for specifying domain of definition is not supported for the moment.
4. `allowfemdbc` is no more than a converter for `NeumannValue`, so if certain b.c. cannot be expressed with `NeumannValue`, `allowfemdbc` won't help, either.

### Usage

The usage `allowfemdbc` is simple, just add it before `NDSolve` / `NDSolveValue` / `NDEigenvalues`  `NDEigensystem`!

If you feel worried about the correctness of the obtained `NeumannValue`, set 2nd argument of `allowfemdbc` to `Inactive` to check the generated code. You can also add a `Reap` to extract the generated system.

### Example

**1**

```
sys = {y''[x] + y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[30] == 1};

asol = DSolveValue[sys, y, {x, 0, 30}];

nsol = allowfemdbc@NDSolveValue[sys, y, {x, 0, 30}, Method -> FiniteElement];

Plot[{asol, nsol}[x] // Through // Evaluate, {x, 0, 30}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]
```

[image]

**2**

[How to input Robin boundary conditions for nonstandard Laplace equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147089/1871)

```
Clear[bc]
xmax = 1; ymax = 1;
epsilon = 0.5; n = 0.1;
With[{u = u[x, y]}, eq = epsilon^2 D[u, x, x] + D[u, y, y] == 1;
 {bc@x, bc@y} = {{D[u, x] == 0 /. x -> 0, 
    u == -2 epsilon n D[u, x] /. x -> xmax}, {D[u, y] == 0 /. y -> 0, 
    u == -2 n D[u, y] /. y -> ymax}};]

solfem = allowfemdbc@NDSolveValue[{eq, bc /@ {x, y}}, 
                                  u, {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}];

Plot3D[solfem[x, y], {x, 0, xmax}, {y, 0, ymax}]
```

[image]

**3**

[How to solve 2D eigenvalue problem with robin boundary conditions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/268436/1871)

```
With[{u = u[x, y]}, lhs = Laplacian[u, {x, y}];
  bc = {u == 0 /. {{x -> -1}, {y -> -1}},
    {2 D[u, x] + u == 0 /. x -> 1,
     D[u, y] + u == 0 /. y -> 1}}];

tsthold = allowfemdbc[
  NDEigensystem[{lhs, bc} // Flatten, u, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 4, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}], Inactive]
(*
Inactive[NDEigensystem][{-NeumannValue[-u[x, y], y == 1] - 
   NeumannValue[-(1/2) u[x, y], x == 1] - 
   Inactive[Div][(-{{1, 0}, {0, 1}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}], 
  u[-1, y] == 0, u[x, -1] == 0}, u, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 4, 
 Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}]
 *)

tst = Activate[tsthold];
Plot3D[tst[[2, 1]][x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]